# Analyzing "Reverberation"

Tags: r, time-series, marketing

I'm trying to measure the reverberation so to speak of a variable - and its effect on itself in the subsequent units of time and its effect on other variables.

For example `var1` will have an event where it generates 20 units on day one.  I'd like to analyze what happens to `var1` on day two, day three, and so on.  But also what happens to `var 2` on day one, day two, and so on.

My measurements look like this:
`var1: 20,19,17....`,
`var2: 15,15,16....`,

What is the best way to go about this?  (any helpful R packages would also be great)

---

EDIT: Here's what I mean by reverberation in my case.

A TV ad is shown on Monday.  I can measure the impact of that, but how do I model it over the next few days.  Also, when that ad runs on Monday, presumably, there will be more internet hits as well (which I can measure).  How can I model the relationship to the TV ad and how long the effect lasts.

I was thinking maybe survival analysis or something along those lines.  But I'm familiar with survival analysis at the wikipedia level along.

Comment: Sorry but it's really not clear (to me anyway) what you mean by 'reverberation'.

Comment: Gotcha, I've edited the post as people sometimes don't look in comments.

Comment: Would this be similar to the concept of signal decay?